# kendo grid not displaying inside pop up

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, kendo-ui

- I am new to angular 2 and kendo UI.
- I am trying to add the grid inside my pop up.
- I was able to show the pop-up.
- but when I add the grid  its not showing.
- can you guys tell me how to fix it?
- in the console, I dont see any errors too.
- i am trying to display the pop up using the kendo ui.  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index
- sample working code http://jsfiddle.net/XY7HT/53/
- providing related code below and complete code in the fiddle since no space to paste it here https://jsfiddle.net/9bwdk6xk/4/

```or-tag-here
    <div class="waterPaperDocInfo">                 
            <span class="fa fa-file-text-o"></span>
            <span class="cat" (click)="cloud();">&nbsp;{{hat.paper}} paper</span> | Last Modified: {{hat.finger}} &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-clock-o">9:00 am</span>
    </div>

    <div id="win1" style="display:none">
        <p>First Window</p>
        <button type="button" id="open2">Open second Window</button>
            <input type="file" name="batchFile" id="batchFile" title="Select file" />
        <div id="grid"></div>

    </div>


$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        selectable: "multiple cell",
        allowCopy: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "productName" },
            { field: "category" }
        ],
        dataSource: [
            { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
            { productName: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
            { productName: "Ham", category: "Food" },
            { productName: "Bread", category: "Food" }
        ]
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if you are using kendo ui with angular2. Check kendo ui for angular 2 web for the guide of the component [here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/)
2. As for angular 2 how you want add component basic step (check depedencies on system.cofig.js if not available download it with npm first-> add the module in app/ng.module.ts -> use it on app.component.ts)
3. This is how you do it in mvvm way-ish (angular2) check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/IYvf1UzZXzKXoGrxFhkO?p=preview), the one u use is the jquery-ish way. i'm not sure if they(kendo) want you to use it like that since i don't see them using it that way in the docs.
4. Just my oppinion though, dont post all your code (so much for ppl to read at least i'm so lazy to read all that)

basically do check this line on ng.module.ts i'm importing grid, button, and dialog adding it to `@NgModule`

```
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { DialogModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog'
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, GridModule, DialogModule, ButtonsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Then you can just use it like :

```
<kendo-dialog title="Kendo Dialog">
     <kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
         //your code goes here
     </kendo-grid>
</kendo-dialog>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...I did not understand the second point...providing the system.config.js in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/25va9nbw/ can you tell me whether I have installed all the packages

Comment: i don't think you included it yet in that fiddle. please take a look at kendo's example or at my plunkr (you can compare it). in it you could see many kendo depedencies being listed such as @progress/kendo-angular-dialog and etc. please read a bit more [here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/#installation)

Comment: I have one more question when I click documents I need to show the pop up...so where should I include kendo-dialog tag after the span  ??

Comment: ` <div id="kgrid" >
                    <kendo-grid-template  ></kendo-grid-template>
                </div> `

 when i use the above lines I am getting the below error, but they have use the same lines at other files but there I dont see any errors, any idea

 EXCEPTION: Error in app/components/financials/finance-dashboard-contract.html:173:46 caused by: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined

Comment: <kendo-dialog title="Kendo Dialog">
                     <kendo-grid>
                     </kendo-grid>
                </kendo-dialog>
 when i use the above lines I am getting the below error, but they have use the same lines at other files but there I dont see any errors, any idea



 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'kendo-grid' is not a known element:

Comment: 1. If 'kendo-grid' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'kendo-grid' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("

                <kendo-dialog title="Kendo Dialog">
                     [ERROR ->]<kendo-grid>

Comment: 1. you can place it anywhere, make sure you hide it at first. 2.they cannot find 'model' or it is undefined. 3. they cannot find kendo grid, are you sure you already follow the instruction from kendo like my provided plunkr?

Comment: Yeah I followed your instructions...but I am confused... can you update in my code :(